# Error while gtags: No space left on device

Tags: linux, temporary-files

I try to use `gtags` first time in my life and got error:

```
/usr/bin/sort: write failed: /tmp/sortDGCa2E: No space left on device
```

`df -h` output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           797M  9.3M  788M   2% /run
/dev/sda1        31G  5.7G   24G  20% /
tmpfs           3.9G   32K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda5       2.9G  278M  2.4G  11% /var
/dev/sda8        64G   15G   47G  24% /home
/dev/sda7       560M   55M  465M  11% /tmp
tmpfs           797M   28K  797M   1% /run/user/115
tmpfs           797M   28K  797M   1% /run/user/1000
```

`df -i` output:

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           1017293    369 1016924    1% /dev
tmpfs          1020112    625 1019487    1% /run
/dev/sda1      2056192 190263 1865929   10% /
tmpfs          1020112      7 1020105    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          1020112      5 1020107    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          1020112     15 1020097    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda5       192384  10240  182144    6% /var
/dev/sda8      4243456 243436 4000020    6% /home
/dev/sda7        37440     74   37366    1% /tmp
tmpfs          1020112     25 1020087    1% /run/user/115
tmpfs          1020112     29 1020083    1% /run/user/1000
```

I search about it a lot, and find out that it is possible to use some flag for `/usr/bin/sort` to use another directory for temporary files, but how to do that for `gtags`? Am I right, `sort` is called inside of it? Some another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/tmp` is a separate mountpoint, the size of the mounted filesystem is reported as `560M`, `465M` is available. Apparently this is not enough for what you are trying to do.

In my Ubuntu `man 1 gtags` describes environment variables the tool uses. One of them is `TMPDIR`:

> `TMPDIR` The location used to stored temporary files. The default is `/tmp`.

No surprise. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TMPDIR):

> `TMPDIR` is the canonical environment variable in Unix and POSIX that should be used to specify a temporary directory for scratch space. Most Unix programs will honor this setting and use its value to denote the scratch area for temporary files instead of the common default of `/tmp` or `/var/tmp`.

There is plenty of space under `/home`. I assume your `$HOME` is inside `/home`. Create your own temporary directory there to use specifically with `gtags`:

```
mkdir "$HOME/tmp_gtags"
```

Now whenever you'd like to use it, you need proper `TMPDIR` variable to be in the environment of `gtags`. Few ways:

1. Either set it beforehand:

   ```
   TMPDIR="$HOME/tmp_gtags"
   export TMPDIR
   ```

   From now on all commands in this shell session (and their descendants) will inherit `TMPDIR` as a part of the environment (in general commands may change their environment though). You can run `gtags` then:

   ```
   gtags …
   ```
2. Or you can specify the variable only for one specific command. The general form is

   ```
   variable=value some_command arguments
   ```

   In your case:

   ```
   TMPDIR="$HOME/tmp_gtags" gtags …
   ```
3. Or you can use `gtags.conf` for this. See `man 5 gtags.conf`:

   > You  can  use the following environment variables as a string variable. If these variables are set then environment variables of the same name are set before command execution.
   >   […]
   >   `TMPDIR`

   Refer to the manual to find out the syntax. I think one cannot use `$HOME` in `gtags.conf`. *I have only briefly studied the manual and not tested at all, so do your own research.* For now I believe the setting would be like

   ```
   :TMPDIR=/home/anton/tmp_gtags:
   ```

Keep in mind while your OS may do [some maintenance and cleanup in `/tmp`](https://askubuntu.com/a/609396/693277), maintaining `tmp_gtags` is your job.